# how to access defines and structs inside a .h from C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke

In accessing PDH.dll (a Win32 API) [(see link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373228%28VS.85%29.aspx) using [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx), it turns out that I need access to several constants and structs. I found these are defined inside a file PDH.h.

How do I access these defines and structs? Do I have to rewrite them with C#? Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to rewrite them in C#

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, you need to rewrite them in C#. But if you are lucky, someone will have already done them for you at [PInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/index.aspx)

Alternatively, you could try using the [Interop Signature Toolkit](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120), which can generate C# definitions from a C header file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite them in C#.

Comment: On the plus side, more often than not it's a pretty trivial conversion!